# Creating custom Live Tile

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I create custom live tile? I want something very simple. Only a number to display, no icon, no text or count... and it should be possible to update the tile also.

Comment: If you only want a number can you not just set the count property and set title to the empty string and?

Comment: I can, but the count icon is very small so it doesnt fit very well...

Comment: So you want one large number on the tile - how many possible numbers are there?

Comment: 1-200, too many I think to generate all the pictures...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the [Ree7 Tile Toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://wp7tiletoolkit.codeplex.com/) might be what you're after. It allows you to define tiles in XAML and render them out as a custom tile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something?

By googling I found this: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/11/31-days-of-mango-day-11-live-tiles/
Should help you going your way, no?

Comment: The article shows how to change background, text etc. I already know how to do it... I want to have a custom tile...